# Expect, Command, Pipes and Gzip

Tags: expect

I am trying to work with the expect command, everything works well until I try to pipe the results of a command into a Gzip file. Here is the snippet of the bash file:

```
XYZ=$(expect -c "
spawn python log-connector.py -s $strt -e $end -i 600 -a https://server:9000 -u someaccount -f ./conf/firewall-fields2.txt -q ./conf/query.txt -z | gzip >> /data/sources/results-$strt2-$end2.json.gz

expect \"Password:\"

send \"$pass\r\"

interact

")

echo "$XYZ"
```

`$start` - variable (start date)
`$end`   - variable (end date)
`$strt2` - variable (start date with 00:00)
`$end2`  - variable (end date with 23:59)
`$pass` - Password entered by the user previously.

If I remove

```
| gzip >> /data/sources/results-$strt2-$end2.json.gz
```

from the above it works as expected. When I add it I get the following error:

```
send: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing

usage: API [-h] [-s START] [-e END] [-d DAY] [-i INTERVAL]
                    [-a LOGGER] [-l LOGFILE] [-f FIELDS] [-q QUERY]
                    [-o OUTPUT] [-t FORMAT] [-u USER] [-p PASS] [-z]
API: error: unrecognized arguments: | gzip >> /data/sources/results-20180604-20180604.json.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a shell to interpret the pipe and redirection: I'll use a heredoc to make quoting easier

```
XYZ=$(expect <<END_EXPECT
    set timeout -1
    spawn sh -c {python log-connector.py -s $strt -e $end -i 600 -a https://server:9000 -u someaccount -f ./conf/firewall-fields2.txt -q ./conf/query.txt -z | gzip >> /data/sources/results-$strt2-$end2.json.gz}
    expect "Password:"
    send "$pass\r"
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
)

echo "$XYZ"
```

Comment: Well, I thought this did the trick and it sort of does, It runs the the python script once, gets the first chunk of a 10 min log, but does not continue getting the others. So its not really executing to completeness

Comment: It should go until I get to the $end2 - variable (end date with 23:59), is there a way to check this in the expect ?

Comment: If it takes longer than 10 seconds then `set timeout -1` at the top of the expect body

Comment: It can take 10 minutes like it could take a few hours for the logs to be parsed, so will the set timeout -1 handle this ?  Also at the top of the expect body, you mean before XYZ=$.

Comment: -1 means "do not time out". Put it before spawn